# Syncing computer to internal server time

Tags: linux, networking, ntp, crunchbang

I'm trying to sync my PC time with an internal server but I'm not sure if it's working.

I've added the internal server to NTP.conf as below:

```
colin@colin:~$ sudo geany /etc/ntp.conf

server 193.61.148.167 prefer
server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

This is the results of ntpdc -c peers

```
remote           local      st poll reach  delay   offset disp
=======================================================================
=mca167.scm.ulst 193.61.148.73    1   64    1 0.00122 -298.2700 2.81874
=ns1.nexellent.n 193.61.148.73   16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 3.99217
=1.ntp.tld.sk    193.61.148.73   16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 3.99217
=time.ostseehaie 193.61.148.73   16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 3.99217
=ns393034.ovh.ne 193.61.148.73   16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 3.99217
```

And the result of ntpdc -c sysinfo

```
system peer:          0.0.0.0
system peer mode:     unspec
leap indicator:       11
stratum:              16
precision:            -20
root distance:        0.00000 s
root dispersion:      0.00021 s
reference ID:         [73.78.73.84]
reference time:       00000000.00000000  Mon, Jan  1 1900 0:00:00.000
system flags:         auth monitor ntp kernel stats
jitter:               0.000000 s
stability:            0.000 ppm
broadcastdelay:       0.000000 s
authdelay:            0.000000 s
```

To me it doesn't look like it's working as 193.61.148.73 is my PC IP and the IP of the server is 193.61.148.167

EDIT: apologies of the formatting I'm on my phone and can't figure out the code tags.

Comment: Are you sure your firewall is permitting NTP?  Most of your peers appear to be unreachable.  If you are not going to permit them, then you really should comment out the pool.ntp.org lines.  It does seem to be able to access 193.61.148.167 (ie mca167.scm.ulster.ac.uk) server.

Comment: I'm not sure about the firewall, I'm on a managed environment so it wouldn't surprise me if it was locked down. Also may I ask how you know that the other hosts are unreachable? Is it the fact that delay and offset are all 0's?

Answer (score 0):

How long was your ntp running when you took those stats?

You appear to be hosted on Ja.net so you will find a lot of things a blocked/restricted by your establishment.

You have a `reach` of `64` with a `poll` of `16`sec so it looks like you can reach the servers - you just need to wait a while longer - you need a higher reach value before things settle down.

In order to diag your problem a bit better please comment out or remove all of the invalid servers from your `ntp.conf` file leaving only the server you want to sync too.

Restart ntp and see if your `reach` increases if it does wait a while then give us the output from `ntpq -pcrv` if it still appears not to be working. Given ntp likes to have a least 3 servers to work with you may want to look at how you do your time setup. Ja.net run there own time hierarchy so you might want to look into that and source your time 'on-net' as it where.